# Count the No of Element of a column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

```
public ActionResult NoOfLeaves()
{
 string CurrentUserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
 var result = (from u in db.LeaveTypes
 join s in db.LeaveDetails
 on new { id = u.LeaveTypeID } equals new { id = s.LeaveTypeID}
 join user in db.Users
 on new { id = s.EmpID } equals new { id = user.Id }
 where user.Id == CurrentUserID   
 select new noOfLeavesView
  {
    EmployeeID = user.Id,
    EmployeeName = user.Name,
    LeaveTypeName = u.LeaveTypeName,
    Issued = u.NoOfLeaves

  });                            
 return View(result);
}
```

Leave type contains the type of Leaves Medical,etc.
Leave Detail contains the History of Leaves Applied by the User.
I want to know how many medical leaves were applied by a user.

Comment: Do you mean you want to group by a column and count the results?

Comment: You will need to be a bit more precise. Generally speaking, you can use `.GroupBy()`. Can you give sample input and sample expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult NoOfLeaves()
{
var result = (from u in db.LeaveTypes
join s in db.LeaveDetails
on new { id = u.LeaveTypeID } equals new { id = s.LeaveTypeID }

select new noOfLeavesView
 {
 LeaveTypeName = LeaveTypeId.LeaveTypeName,
Issued = u.NoOfLeaves,
Availed = (db.LeaveDetails.Where(i=>i.LeaveTypeID.Equals(s.LeaveTypeID)).Count()),
 }).Distinct();


            return View(result);
        }
```

from this way i get the required results...